# How to get text/html; charset=utf-8 in response of request in iOS Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, request

I send request to server with url.
When PO my response , "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
And now i don't know how to detect and pars this data.
my code is here :

```
//Send request
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

I have used to use this code for Json:

```
NSDictionary *backDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil ];
```

And this code for XML:

```
//Get response from server as XML
backDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data options:XMLReaderOptionsProcessNamespaces
                                                 error:&error];
```

But does not work any of both.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your response data is `html` then simply convert that data to string.

`NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

And you'll have your response.

But you should consider to avoid getting useful data in html, it's hard to parse.